# How to stop blinking when particular div is reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

i have used setTimeout function for reload my notification drop down, now it's working well, but my notification drop down is blinking when it's reloaded,please give any solution to stop that blinking.

Here i attach what i already use.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    notification();
  });

function notification()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#notification_ico').load('<?php echo base_url();?>/Filemanagement/noti_refresh');
        notification();
    }, 3000);
}
function abc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("notification_ico").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url();?>/Filemanagement/noti_refresh", true);
        xhttp.send();
        }
```

My page is not working

Comment: you are calling notification() function again after reload inside timedout which is causing recursive calling of notification function again and again and causing blinking

Comment: i need to show the recent notification that's why i call the notification function inside of setTimeout function,so it's call notification function at every 3 seconds

Comment: you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that each time you call notification you invoke a new setTimeout without killing the previous one, so you end up with several executions in parallel.

You should use setInterval instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $('#notification_ico').load('<?php echo base_url();>/Filemanagement/noti_refresh');
  }, 1000);
});
```

You can try it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-chts5e

Comment: it's not refresh it self